# Not a real answer, but accepted nevertheless

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Regarding this question : [Temps surcomposés](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/79/temps-surcomposes).

As the comments point out, the accepted answer is hardly even adressing the very question raised. I wouldn't flag it as “not an answer” for it *tries* to adress the issue, but it **is** misleading to the newcomer who wouldn't read thoroughly the comments.

I don't know the answer, but I'm pretty sure this is not it.

---

À propos de : [Temps surcomposés](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/79/temps-surcomposes).

Comme le statuent les commentaires, la réponse acceptée ne traite même pas vraiment du problème que pose le demandeur. Je ne la draperai pas de l'accusation `not an answer`, reconnaissant un certain effort dans la contribution, mais en l'état, **c'est** trompeur pour qui ne prêterait pas assez d'attention aux commentaires, et même alors, le fait que la réponse soit acceptée reste déroutant.

Je ne connais pas ni la ni de réponse à cette question, mais je suis confiant que ceci ne l'est pas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Accepted answers are solely determined by the asker. There are some downsides to having this system in parallel with the “upvoting/downvoting” system, but it is a deliberate choice of design of the SE system. The usual way to override this is to write a better answer, let it be up voted, and optionally leave a comment for the OP to ask him to consider switching the “accept” tick. Even if that does not happen, enough downvotes on the accepted answer will make it clear that it is not to be trusted too much!

For the specific case you link to, being the author of the answer, I have deleted it :)
I would argue that it *is* an answer, though… even if it's a *wrong* answer. “Not an answer” is for posts that do not answer the question at all, outside of arguability over whether they are right or wrong. If the question is “what color are green peas?”, “green” is an answer, but “peas are hot” is not an answer.

Comment: Indeed, I do agree it **is** an answer. (I thought I made that clear ? If I believed that, I would've flagged it.) “Red” is also an answer to “what color are green peas?” But I'd still raise a flag if it was the accepted one, be it on meta or for ♦ attention.

Answer (score 3):

The acceptance checkmarks are for answers that "make a lightbulb go on" in the head of the OP. This is often, but by no means always, the objectively best answer.

Sometimes the OP is fixated on one particular point, and an answer that hits that one point hardest will be accepted over a more broadly correct answer.